# How to change the decimals in my lsmeans output

Tags: r, decimal

Forgive my lack of R knowledge. I am running some statistics, however I have some problems with the number of decimals in the output. The table I use is simple, inlcuding 2 colums of 'text' and two 'numeric'. The table shows 5 digits (3 decimals). However when working with this table R studio only gives 1 decimal. Not only in my lsmeans results but already in my head(X).

I already tried the following (where X is data):

```
>format(X, digits=5)

>format(X, decimals=3)

>print(lsmeans,decimals=3)

>options(digits = 5)
```

However the columns N and Dm are still rounded to 1 decimal.

```
> N   92.4   92.4  93.7 .....         
> Dm  44.8 51.2 49.0 ....

> lsmean 92.7  93.3 92.2
```

I would like to see the columns N and Dm with 3 decimals like (I see them at the table when used view(x)), and likewise the results of N of the lsmean.

**Example data:**

```
X <- structure(list(Diet = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                                     .Label = c("1", 
                                                "2", "3", "4"), 
                                     class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
                    Room = structure(c(1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
                                     .Label = c("1", "2"), class = c("ordered", 
                                                                     "factor")), 
                    Ndigestibility = c(92.3961026914675, 91.3131265857907, 
                                       93.7094576131358, 93.1557358031795, 
                                       91.6853770290382, 93.2698082975574), 
                    Dmdigestibility = c(44.7692224966736, 51.2173172537712, 
                                        49.0100980168149, 45.6289084300095, 
                                        45.9036710781654, 45.3144774487225)), 
               row.names = c(NA, 
                             -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

X
#   Diet Room Ndigestibility Dmdigestibility
# 1    1    1       92.39610        44.76922
# 2    1    1       91.31313        51.21732
# 3    1    1       93.70946        49.01010
# 4    1    1       93.15574        45.62891
# 5    1    1       91.68538        45.90367
# 6    1    2       93.26981        45.31448
```

Comment: Could you provide reproducible example, output of `dput(head(X))` ?

Comment: Maybe try `print(X, digits = 5)` ?

Comment: I tried print(X, digits = 5) as well and just gives again 3 digits in my column N.

Comment: assuming the information is still in those values, and not simply being truncated already, you should be able to get them with `sprintf`: *e.g.* `sprintf(fmt = "%.3f", 2.3)`

Comment: If I take (X) or (N) for the 2.3, so >sprint(fmt = "%.3f, N) I get the notification: Error in sprintf(fmt = "%.3f", N) : 
  object 'N' not found

Comment: As Marc said, that then suggests that the input is already truncated there. It seems only on the general table are the three (or many!) decimals left. The best might be to just create your own table--a path in some such cases. It's about gathering the output vector by vector into a dataframe, with which you can create a custom table (e.g., using knitr::kable). You probably know round() already.

Comment: @zx875; In the code above you can see that for Ndigestibility (I used N for short) has 15 digits! Still it does not show in my output table.

Comment: I can't replicated the issue, this works fine with your example data: for the full dataframe `format(X, digits = 5)` and for the selected column: `print(X$Dmdigestibility, digits = 5)`

Comment: I've changed my table in Excel to 3 decimals. However when I use sprintf(fmt = "%.3f", X) I will get the notification: Error in sprintf(fmt = "%.3f", X) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'.

Comment: `sprintf` takes only a vector, no other objects. This means that you'll have to round each column individually. You can do this using some helper functions like `lapply` or `sapply` if it's too much trouble to do it by hand. See Marc's answer (e.g. `X$N_3digits <- sprintf(fmt = "%.3f", X$Ndigestibility)`).

Comment: @zx8754 with `print(X$Dmdigestibility, digits = 5)` I indeed see a long list with the correct data. However this does not change my lsmeans output `lsmeans(a, pairwise~Diet, adjust="tukey")` it gives still 1 decimal output on the lsmeans. Is it possible  to  change this?

Comment: @emily, note that `lsmeans` is being replaced by `emmeans`. I've tried `emmeans` now and I get four decimals even on the most reduced output (about replacement: https://rdrr.io/cran/lsmeans/man/transition.html).

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at that.

Comment: Nope still not working for the output on both `emmeans` as for `lsmeans`. The output will give me for example 92.7, where I want 92.73 I've tried it for for an other dataset as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
emm_options(opt.digits = FALSE)
```

This will disable the feature in the **emmeans** package (for which **lsmeans** is a front end) whereby results are displayed in reasonable precision relative to their standard errors.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the answer I was looking for!